# How to update nested array (multi react-select)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select

I'm creating an app where I need to store selected values in array nested in object (category below). State looks like:

```
state = {
    data: {
        user: "",
        title: "",
        text: "",
        category: [], // should store values
    },
    updateNoteId: null,
}
```

In my render() I have following form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitNote}>
    <Select
        name="category"
        value={this.state.data.category}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.handleMultiChange}
        multi
    />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Options are:

```
const options = [
    { value: 1, label: 'one' },
    { value: 2, label: 'two' },
    { value: 3, label: 'three' }
]
```

So the question is how `this.handleMultiChange` function should looks like to work. Category[] need to keep all values selected in Select which is react-select component (eg. it should be category = [1,3], when 'one' and 'three' were chosen). I tried many combination but none of them worked so far. I prefer to use ES6 without any external libraries/helpers to do that.

Comment: Show what you have tried as a [mcve] along with an explanation of your results.

Answer (score 2):

```
handleMultiChange(selectedOptions) {
  this.setState({ 
    data: {
      ...this.state.data, 
      categories: selectedOptions
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it's not working. Console show undefined values and Select seems also to work incorrect... I've prepared codesandbox -> (https://codesandbox.io/s/6108wxlqxn)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you was using React-Select. Working Code Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/502qv3qp4k

I've also updated my answer